# How to Change color while in a repeat in turtle

Tags: python, colors, repeat, turtle-graphics

I have everything set up with the process of my initials being repeated working properly, however, I need the color to change after each repeat. (I know this question has been asked before I just did not understand the answers)

```
import turtle 
s = turtle.Turtle()
s.color("purple")



def Square(turtle):
for i in range(4):
    s.left(90)
    s.forward(150)
 s.right(20)


for i in range(16):
Square(s.right(20))
Square(s.right(10))
Square(s.right(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle 
s = turtle.Turtle()

#Create list of colors you want
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "pink", "yellow"]

def Square(turtle):
    for i in range(4):

        #Choosing color from list- this option is repeating colors at list from first to last 
        color_number = i % len(colors)
        current_color = colors[color_number] 

        #Here you set color you want
        s.color(current_color)

        s.left(90)
        s.forward(150)
        s.right(20)

for i in range(16):
    Square(s.right(20))
    Square(s.right(10))
    Square(s.right(20))
```

Comment: Hi MatoX_svk , Thanks for contributing your answer with stack overflow , please try to post description instead of directly giving the code solution i.e description + code